# How can I set a onLongItemClickListener on a list generated with SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview

I am generating a list from my app's database with a `SimpleCursorAdapter`:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mCursor,
         new String[] { DataManager.TITLE },
         new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }, 0);

setListAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

If I was using a ListView and ListAdapter, I would set a long click listener thus:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

list.setAdapter(mAdapter); // set the list view adapter

// enable long clicking on the list item
list.setLongClickable(true);

// detect long clicks and respond accordingly
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           // do stuff
           return true;
       }
});
```

But as I don't have a `ListView` explicitly declared, I can't do this. How do I do it with a list generated by `SimpleCursorAdapter`?

Comment: what do you mean you don't have it declared?

Comment: I mean, I don't have a ListView variable to set a listener on.

Comment: you have no `ListView`? so where are you showing your data?

Comment: In a Fragment (I'm extending ListFragment).

Comment: it has `getListView()` method

Comment: Throws an error: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created

Comment: call it inside `onViewCreated`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I think you used `ListActivity` or `ListFragment`

then what you can do is write this in `onViewCreated()` not in `onCreateView()`

```
getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           // do stuff
           return true;
       }
});
```

Comment: Done - only just got the rep to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you using SimpleCusrsorAdapter like this ?

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listitemlayout, c, from, to);
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

What are you doing in

> setListAdapter(cursorAdapter)

?

Comment: I'm using SImpleCursorAdapter as it is in my question. I don't know the inner workings of setListAdapter: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#setListAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29

Comment: You should have a ListView anyway http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/UsingSimpleCursorAdapterandListView.htm